# why am i getting a invalid child error on an iso message

Tags: xml, iso

I am trying to create an ISO message and I seem to be getting the following error

"Invalid ISO20022 Message received. Reason Code : 9901, Description : Schema Violation - cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'CdtrAgtPtyInf'. No child element is expected at this point. , Host Rec Id : 1346224547942110371"

This is the part with CdtrAgtPtyInf

```
        <SplmtryData>
            <Envlp>
                <Document xmlns="http://iso20022.dovetailsys.com/SupplementaryData/INSandADV/2014/01">
                    <InsAndAdv>
                        <InternalInf>Contact Person: XXXXXXX (111) 111-1111</InternalInf>
                        <CdtrAgtPtyInf>
                            <InstrInf>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</InstrInf>
                        </CdtrAgtPtyInf>
                    </InsAndAdv>
                </Document>
            </Envlp>
        </SplmtryData>
```

Can someone please help. I am not a developer or anything its just a learning process

Answer (score 0):

ISO-20022 is a financial industry standard. You need to download their XML Schemas and make sure that your XML is valid against the appropriate XML Schema.

URL to get ISO-20022 XML Schemas: [ISO 20022 Message Definitions](https://www.iso20022.org/iso-20022-message-definitions)

Comment: I found it from your link.
its under pacs "payment and clearing system" and its pac 008.
Within the tree view its xs# 146

sorry I did look and found

supplementary data1
max occurs 1
min occurs 1
I appreciate you helping me
Should I make this into 2 separate data ?
                    <InsAndAdv>
                        <InternalInf>X</InternalInf>
                    </InsAndAdv>

                    <InsAndAdv>
                        <CdtrAgtPtyInf>
                            <InstrInf>X</InstrInf>
                        </CdtrAgtPtyInf>

@Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: if I look at this and I get this error
"Invalid content was found starting with element 'CdtrAgtPtyInf'. No child element is expected at this point."
what does it mean by child element  in layman term ?

If I just make them into 2 separate supplementary data would that work and resolve the issue ?

@Yitzhak Khabinsky and thank you again